# Video is not playing in Android TV Emulator

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview, android-tv

I am developing an android TV application where I was working on the sample TV app given in android studio template. Here everything works fine, but on the video player screen, it shows 'Can't play this video' error in Android TV Emulator.

Ref file *PlaybackOverlayActivity.java*=>*onFragmentPlayPause()* (when we create new TV project in android studio)

In demo, they used **videoview**. I also tried using **surface view/ texture view** to play video from a link, but it gives different errors like

1.MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)

2.MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

3.MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)

I have already tried different solutions from different threads...

Please check below code, its just for testing video playback. 
I also have found that any emulator created from AVD can not play video by any of these methods.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {


        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        private TextureView mPreview;

        private String path = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

            super.onCreate(icicle);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mPreview = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
            mPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
        }

        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Surface s = new Surface(surface);

            try {
                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(path));
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    }
```

[image: android-tv-cant-play-video]

Also tell if there is any other way to test videos on Android TV Emulator. Thanks.

Comment: is it working in normal mobile emulator??

Comment: I have mentioned that 'I also have found that any emulator created from AVD can not play video'. But it plays in the genymotion emulator(phone).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you take a look at the [Android TV Leanback sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback), which is more actively maintained than the Android Studio templates. In the Leanback sample, it can show you how to use ExoPlayer to play content.

In addition, there was recent changes made to the Android emulator that fixed a critical issue where network access wasn't available via the emulator, effectively making it impossible to fetch videos. Make sure you have updated to latest API23_x86 and API23_arm emulators to get this fix.